# How is it possible to restart Tomcat in Linux from a webapp inside Tomcat?

Tags: java, linux, bash, tomcat

I tried this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c " + System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/logs/shutdown.sh && " + System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/bin/startup.sh");
```

But only shutdown worked properly, Tomcat didn't startup properly, I think the problem was that the previous instance still used port 8080. I added a sleep 2m between the two commands (seperated with &&), but in this case, shutdown occured, but nothing happened later according to catalina log, no error, startup wasn't executed at all.

(First time I tried without /bin/bash -c, but in that case nothing happened.)

Comment: So if you've shutdown the server and all the applications running in it, how do you expect it to get started again by one of the applications?

Comment: I except that it's started again by shell. This worked in Windows:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start shutdown.bat && start startup.bat");

Comment: Is it possible to run the sleep and the startup in a background process, and seperately the shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)`. It doesn't work the way people expect. Use the version that accepts a `String[]` instead.

Also, run it in the background and redirect stdout/stderr, otherwise it will block waiting for the java process to read its input.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { 
  "/bin/bash", "-c",
  "(" + 
    System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/bin/shutdown.sh && " +          
    System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/bin/startup.sh" +
  ") > ~/restart.log 2>&1 &"
});
```

Here it writes to `~/restart.log`, so that if it fails, you can see the error messages. You can replace this with `/dev/null` when it works.

I would strongly recommend creating a new script `restart_tomcat` that does all this backgrounding and redirection, so that you can reduce this to

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/path/to/restart_tomcat" });
```

It's easier and more flexible to work with a script on the file system than a script embedded in Java code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before you answered, I tried the same with exec(String), but it didn't work, but this solution almost works, the only problem with it is that shutdown.sh also starts a background process, that stops tomcat, while main process returns, so startup.sh starts before shutdown is ended, so Tomcat cannot be started properly, as the its ports are still used.

That's why I added sleep 2m between the 2 script, and it works now (shutdown of tomcat with current apps is much less than 2 minutes).